# Can't get card brand from Stripe

Tags: go, stripe-payments

```
func (s *Service) CreateNewCreditCard(user *models.User, creditCardRequest *CreditCardRequest) (error) {

    userID := string(user.ID)
    customer, err := s.stripe_a.CreateUserID(creditCardRequest.StripeToken, userID)

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    //TO DO - NOT BEING FILLED WITH DATA --> this needs to be added to the brand colom in the database
    //customer.DefaultSource.Card.Brand

    // Save to the DB
    stripeCustomer := &models.StripeCustomer{
        UserID:         util.IntOrNull(int64(user.ID)),
        CustomerID:     util.StringOrNull(customer.ID),
        Last4:          util.StringOrNull(creditCardRequest.Last4),
        Brand:          util.StringOrNull("VISA"),
    }
    if err := s.db.Create(stripeCustomer).Error; err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

I'm trying to get the card's brand of the default card for the user that customer that I'm inserting into my database but this always lead to a crash because of a null pointer.

I don't get why though. In the Stripe console the customer has a default card displaying "VISA"

Added logs:

```
[2017-06-14 04:26:40]  [18.51ms]  SELECT * FROM "orders"  WHERE "orders"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND (("user_id" IN ('2'))) ORDER BY "orders"."id" ASC
2017/06/14 04:26:40 Requesting POST api.stripe.com/v1/customers
2017/06/14 04:26:41 [C] [asm_amd64.s:514] the request url is  /v1/credit-cards
2017/06/14 04:26:41 [C] [asm_amd64.s:514] Handler crashed with error runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
2017/06/14 04:26:41 [C] [asm_amd64.s:514] /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:514
2017/06/14 04:26:41 [C] [asm_amd64.s:514] /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:489
2017/06/14 04:26:41 [C] [asm_amd64.s:514] /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:63
2017/06/14 04:26:41 [C] [asm_amd64.s:514] /usr/local/go/src/runtime/signal_unix.go:290
```

This is the CreateUserID function:

```
func (a *Adapter) CreateUserID(stripeToken string, userID string) (*stripe.Customer, error) {
    // Assign secret key from configuration to Stripe
    stripe.Key = a.cnf.Stripe.SecretKey

    // Create a Customer:
    customerParams := &stripe.CustomerParams{
        Desc: userID,
    }
    customerParams.SetSource(stripeToken)

    customer, _ := customer.New(customerParams)

    return customer, nil
}
```

How can I make it ask for the card's brand?

Comment: What pointer is null? Can you share the error?

Comment: Added logs, doesn't tell me much though

Comment: Then I guess it's up to you to add some `Println`s and figure out where the error happens?

Comment: The error occurs when I put a Println around customer.DefaultSource.Card.Brand

Comment: So maybe `customer.DefaultSource` is `nil`? Or perhaps `customer.DefaultSource.Card`?

Comment: Yea, that's what I don't get. How can they be empty? A Stripe customer gets created with a default card (default source) right?

Comment: Have you determined which value is `nil` yet?

Comment: What library are you using? Stripe's Go SDK doesn't seem to have `CreateUserID` in it.

Comment: According to the Stripe documentation, `DefaultSource` is "expandable," so it's only returned from the server if the client requests it. Maybe you're not asking Stripe to expand that field. (You'd have to look at what the library you're using does.)

Comment: CreateUserID is our own function. I added it to here as well.

Comment: Try a `customerParams.Expand("default_source")` in `CreateUserID`?

Comment: I'll try; adding it above the customerParams.SetSource(stripeToken)

Comment: YOU ARE CORRECT! That was exactly it. Please answer the question and I'll accept your answer as the right one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [the Stripe documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api#customer_object), the `default_card` field is not expanded by default. You can expand it by adding this line to `CreateUserID`:

```
customerParams.Expand("default_source")
```